# docker can't access container from localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I can't access container app from my host. I expect to hit http://localhost:3001/demo and get back a simple text, but the container seems to be unreachable. No firewall is active.
 It is just a simple ExpressJS app I built for testing.
I am running a Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V.

Additionally, running a simple nginx on port 80 works fine. (`docker run nginx -p 80:80`)

This is the result of `docker version`

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Below the code and the dockerfile (It works perfectly fine without docker)

```
// index.js
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/demo', (req, res) => res.json('Demo!'));

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`);
});

// Dockerfile
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /src

ENV PORT=3001

COPY  ["express-app", "."]

EXPOSE 3001

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

I build the image by `docker build -t express -f Dockerfile .`

I run the container by `docker run express -p 3001:3001`

```
docker ps
4840aa7e327d  express  "node index.js -p 30…"  59 seconds ago  Up 58 seconds  3001/tcp wonderful_easley

docker logs 4840aa7e327d
Listening on :::3001
```

Inspecting into the container by doing `docker inspect 4840...` I get

```js
[
    {
        "Id": "4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264",
        "Created": "2020-03-24T04:56:10.774169154Z",
        "Path": "node",
        "Args": [
            "index.js",
            "-p",
            "3001:3001"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2467,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-03-24T04:56:11.148441022Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9fab74e6a051386c4f0820423c35b67565b1d80117a95930e7bf49be58cfac07",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264/4840aa7e327d425d5005d602baf28e8c5f00970e281660f567f340bf7bba3264-json.log",
        "Name": "/wonderful_easley",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                40,
                158
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/673afc4ba0603064a079e0838e3d3993631fbba6e24f5b76f04f371becd78fb5-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/169bcc523e81d71036e2795bf43b93528861b410af969517ed2f70d30f7f10d6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c26dd28589075e2cd12a52a2738924325da791e781f2cb283451a8d6a26fe1b9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c81288f5d63b293cd7fbd2cf566fefbbb805fe59d8c3ffb17de37ca95ba6254b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e113b592e8a485f656fda0974319bc496a7422c9a7d593dcd09a4bb9651bc7ff/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/003113bde6da11ff5455dc2c3ba4d106c36cbd0f3d1b3e82d21b5458041ef3ac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/38c50afa09595d151f3af0bf2857e93e37ac7a4142e74130b6832f3f10039b03/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/172d1d4718751de9e179f7a7f05ac7b4caef6264c8f8b1b67c51b8241984ab36/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15bd99445df3d363b6061a733f69d79dba1fc01268b6fa8c8237a5efedf69479/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68c2b9f8844e997b5406a4250aee4f099394faeada3bcc0046204d3d3ac39ef5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f80954a2a8f4d991965a6538d9521a9ce281589b26e2f228419536a5cc199f5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf0c070105eab104ddd45a1cc7950f80493e394877faa77e1c9f4c52ff2a1967/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/673afc4ba0603064a079e0838e3d3993631fbba6e24f5b76f04f371becd78fb5/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/673afc4ba0603064a079e0838e3d3993631fbba6e24f5b76f04f371becd78fb5/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/673afc4ba0603064a079e0838e3d3993631fbba6e24f5b76f04f371becd78fb5/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "4840aa7e327d",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3001/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=13.10.1",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.0",
                "PORT=3001"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "-p",
                "3001:3001"
            ],
            "Image": "express",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/src",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "node",
                "index.js"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "bafc5bbf61d4c3aef3450caa52479afd9c6a264a89c394d1066b257bf6317768",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3001/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/bafc5bbf61d4",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "86223acb4e1afeb9069d3f6af2f1cbfe59997e21889f6984c60b0cda0d565167",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "32ae384f0621d25edcf263636527296f63474322b9bc6b12efe6867d8efd120d",
                    "EndpointID": "86223acb4e1afeb9069d3f6af2f1cbfe59997e21889f6984c60b0cda0d565167",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

UPDATE:
Container IP address info:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
8: eth0@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From the container I can ping the host machine.

Comment: so what happens when you try to connect to your app?

Comment: what is the output of http://localhost:3001/demo ?

Comment: Can't get a response. It just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the firewall.

I suggest, go to the settings and check **Status** and change connection properties to private and disable only private connection firewall.

I have the same error and it works perfectly disable firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the container with host network

docker run express --network host